# How can I port a Unity game that uses MediaPipe pose detection with Python to Android?

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, mediapipe

It's a little game in which the player moves when you move, mirroring your moves. I want to port it to Android. The problem is that MediaPipe needs an specific Python installation for the tracker to work correctly and I don't know how to do it on Android.

I haven't tried anything because I don't know what to do but I'd like to develop an easy-to-install game, that you can download directly from the Play Store without major complications.

Answer (score 0):

There is [MediaPipeUnityPlugin](https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin) which would be a good starting point.